# How do I keep track of multiple objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am building a page with multiple timers on it. The timers are created when a user clicks a button. So let's say user clicks "K Timer 1" button. The JS created a new timer I want to reference as "KT1" or timers['KT1'].

Here is the way I am trying to do it and you JS peeps are probably laughing at my solution right now. That's OK.  I am much more at home with PHP.

HTML

```
            <button type="button"
                onClick="newUTimer('KT1');">
                Timer 1
            </button>

            <button type="button"
                onClick="newUTimer('KT2');">
                Timer 2
            </button>
```

JS - Old with errors

```
var timers = {};

newUTimer=function(id){
    // If timer does not exist, create it
    if (!globalThis.timers.[id]){
        globalThis.timers.[id] = new CUTimer(id);
        globalThis.timers.[id].starter();

    // If there is already a timer with that ID, reset it
    }else{
        globalThis.timers.[id].reset();
    }
}
```

The reason I need to keep track of the timers is so that I can reset the timer when a user click button for the second time instead of creating another conflicting timer.

JS - UPDATED and Working but not sure this is the correct way I should do this.

```
var timers = {};

newUTimer=function(id){
    // If timer does not exist, create it
    if (!globalThis.timers[id]){
        globalThis.timers[id] = new CUTimer(id);
        globalThis.timers[id].starter();

    // If there is already a timer with that ID, reset it
    }else{
        // Call object resetIt method
        globalThis.timers[id].resetIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is actually wrong with your solution? What isn't it doing that it should? What is it doing that it shouldn't? Do you get any console errors? Finally what is CUTimer?

Comment: @JonP CUTimer is my custom JS timer object that updates the HTML to reflect timer activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the dots before array brackets:
`globalThis.timers.[id].starter()` should be `globalThis.timers[id].starter()`

Comment: Thank you very much,  It works now!  Is there a cleaner way that I should be tracking the timers in this script.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept [aPajos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71152965/4665) as it pointed out your actual error. As for the "more correct way", get rid of inline Javascript

```js
var timers = {};

/*Get the buttons with the data attributes*/
let timerButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-timerid]");
/*Iterate over them adding an event handler*/
timerButtons.forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    /*Get the id from the data atttribute*/
    let timerId = this.dataset.timerid;
    /*Better to go the positive case first*/
    if(timers[timerId]){
      timers[timerId].resetIt();
    }else{
      timers[timerId] = new CUTimer(timerId);
    }
  });
})


function CUTimer(id){
  this.id = id;
  this.starter = function(){console.log("Starting : " + this.id)};
  this.resetIt = function(){console.log("Resetting : " + this.id)};
  //Call your starter method in the construtor
  this.starter();
};
```

```html
<!-- Use Data Attributes to store the timer Id -->
<button type="button" data-timerid='KT1'>Timer 1</button>
<button type="button" data-timerid='KT2'>Timer 2</button>
```